# Do the GnuWin32 tools require the POSIX subsystem to run?

Tags: windows, group-policy, gnu, posix

I would like to remove `Posix` from the Group Policy Object **Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\System settings: Optional Subsystems**.

Do the GnuWin32 tools require the POSIX subsystem to run?

Comment: To clarify I am applying the recommendations of the CIS Benchmark for Windows Server 2008R2 and it recommends disabling the POSIX subsystem if it isn't used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The GnuWin32 tools are (as the name implies) Win32 applications, i.e., they use the Win32 subsystem, not the POSIX subsystem.

Of course, no matter what advice you may receive from strangers on the internet, you should test all your critical applications/services on a test system before making this change on any production systems. :-)

Comment: I'd give another upvote for the advice not to apply Internet advice to production systems without testing.  That is a very unwise practice!

Answer (score 0):

I've never installed/enabled it and GnuWin32 works fine. I don't think the two are related in any way.

Comment: Thank you @gparent.  The trouble is that the POSIX subsystem is on by default :)  That complicates things a bit.

Comment: Are you sure? I always remembered it being an installable component in Windows Server? Either way I'm fairly certain it is obsolete.

Comment: @gparent: I think you may be confusing the POSIX subsystem with what I believe is called something like "Services for UNIX"?  They're related, of course, but distinct.

Comment: Okay, but in both cases the first one is deprecated and the latter is uninstalled. Considered the latter replaces the former, I believe I am right either way. But anyway, this question is pretty silly considering random GNU tools have nothing to do with either.